# Show number of messages in Windows taskbar browser's icon

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core

We have a web application (Asp.Net Core) that also includes a chat component. Is it possible to (javascript?) show the number of new messages in Windows taskbar browser's icon?

A good example of we want to achieve would be how it's done by Skype desktop (see image below):

[image]

Comment: r u using electron to make the app?

Comment: No. Visual studio 2019.

Comment: No, you can not do that from within a normal “web app” that just runs in the browser.

Comment: We cannot help you unless you show us the relevant code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi: I do not think my html/js code plays any role in my question. My question is just simply: is it possible to do that from a web application? Judging from CBroe's commet, I gues not...

Comment: @CBroe: OK, thank you. At least now I know I can stop waisting time on this